# Edit a Text file asynchronously in a servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, asynchronous

I am editing a text file based on a certain `HttpServletResponse` in the `doPost` method of my servlet. Using a firefox poster, when I post a request, the file should be edited.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   JSONObject obj = myrequesthandler.handleRequest(request);
   editTextfile(obj);
}
```

I want this to work in such a manner that until the file is completely edited, no more post requests are entertained by my servlet. It should wait for the editing to finish for the first and then start the editing for second post request.

Comment: Sounds like [filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) are the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using servlet 3.0, I think this is what you need.

From this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet", urlPatterns={"/slowprocess"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        AsyncContext aCtx = request.startAsync(request, response); 
        ServletContext appScope = request.getServletContext();
        ((Queue<AsyncContext>)appScope.getAttribute("slowWebServiceJobQueue")).add(aCtx);
    }
}
```

.

```
@WebServletContextListener
public class SlowWebService implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Queue<AsyncContext> jobQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<AsyncContext>();
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("slowWebServiceJobQueue", jobQueue);
        // pool size matching Web services capacity
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        while(true)
        {
            if(!jobQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                final AsyncContext aCtx = jobQueue.poll();
                executor.execute(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        ServletRequest request = aCtx.getRequest();
                        // get parameteres
                        // invoke a Web service endpoint
                        // set results
                        aCtx.forward("/result.jsp");
                    }                    
                });             
            }
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Johnny. I am looking for a way to just make the editing asynchronous instead of making the entire servlet async. I guess a servlet will handle async calls itself.